# Codeigniter Active Record: Inserting empty records into multiple tables based on an id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using **Codeigniter Active Record Class**

I am trying to **create empty records for a particular id in multiple tables**. For example lets say my user has the id `$user_id`, and I want to `create empty records in tables T1, T2 and T3`. The code I am having trouble with is:

```
        // Store the select statement in cache
        $this->db->start_cache();
        $this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->stop_cache();
        // Insert empty record in tables related to user
        $this->db->insert('T1');
        $this->db->insert('T2');
        $this->db->insert('T3');
        $this->db->flush_cache();
```

An empty record is inserted in table `T1` but then I get the error:

**You must use the "set" method to update an entry.**

**EDIT:** - Obviously, tables `T1, T2 & T3` have `user_id` columns.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? I am new to codeigniter and the CI documentation is not clear about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `$this->db->set()`, you can store the required value in an array and then do the insertion. This may help

```
    // Store the select statement in cache
    $data = array("user_id"=>$user_id);

    // Insert empty record in tables related to user
    $this->db->insert('T1',$data);
    $this->db->insert('T2',$data);
    $this->db->insert('T3',$data);
```

Comment: Hi curious_coder. Many thanks for your reply! This is exactly what I was looking for. Works and is elegant :) Thanks once again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    // Store the select statement in cache
    $this->db->cache_on();
    $this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->cache_off();
    // Insert empty record in tables related to user
    $this->db->insert('T1');
    //$this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->insert('T2');
    //$this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->insert('T3');
    $this->db->cache_delete_all();
```

Comment: Hi Danish, of course this will work, but I cached the statement earlier `$this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);` exactly to avoid repeating this statement :(. Was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Hi Danish, your new solution doesn't work either :(. Nevertheless, check out the solution from curious_coder below which works. I definitely learned something new. Thank you so much for your help anyways. :)